# emacsclient unable to connect to daemon under snap installation of Emacs

Tags: emacsclient, daemon, snap

I am facing with a well know problem, when I try to start `emacs --daemon` on a remote machine, I am getting following error `emacsclient: connect: Connection refused`:

```
$ ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs"  # returns empty
$ emacsclient -t -q doo.py
emacsclient: connect: Connection refused

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
## ...
Starting Emacs daemon.
Unable to start the daemon.
Another instance of Emacs is running the server, either as daemon or interactively.
You can use emacsclient to connect to that Emacs process.
Error: server did not start correctly
Error: Could not start the Emacs daemon
```

---

The way I connect into the remote machine `ssh -Y4t user@IP zsh --login -i`

- I have done this [set-up X11 Forwarding over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033038/2402577) an it works, where `xclock` displays gui.
- `echo $DISPLAY` => `workstation:10.0`

I don't know what can I debug more to handle this or what is the issue. I also have same configuration on a different remote machine where it works without a problem.

---

**Update** based on @phils guide(please see in comments) debug in depth.

```
$ kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs" | awk '{print $2}')
$ ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs"  # returns empty
$ emacsclient -t -q doo.py
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.

$ ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs"  # returns empty
netlab    9885 14.1  0.4 464628 67812 ?        Ssl  01:40   0:04 /snap/emacs/296/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
$ kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs" | awk '{print $2}')
$ ps aux | grep -E "[e]macs"  # returns empty

$ unset ALTERNATE_EDITOR
$ echo $ALTERNATE_EDITOR

$ ls -l /tmp/emacs1002/server
srwx------ 1 netlab netlab 0 Jul 16 01:40 /tmp/emacs1002/server
$ rm -rf /tmp/emacs1002/server
$ ls -l /tmp/emacs1002/server
ls: cannot access '/tmp/emacs1002/server': No such file or directory
$ emacsclient -t
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
$ emacs -Q --daemon

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
Emacs might crash when run in daemon mode and the X11 connection is unexpectedly lost.
Using an Emacs configured with --with-x-toolkit=lucid does not have this problem.
Starting Emacs daemon.
$ ls -l /tmp/emacs1002/server
srwx------ 1 netlab netlab 0 Jul 16 01:42 /tmp/emacs1002/server
$  emacsclient -t
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    --socket-name
    --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Comment: Perhaps there's an issue accessing the socket?  What if you start `emacs` (non-server), and then `M-x server-force-delete` ?

Comment: It returns `Connection file "/tmp/emacs1002/server" deleted`. But when I start the daemon again I have face with the same error

Comment: I also realized having `(xclip-mode 1)` in the init file makes paste operation pretty slow but removing it also did not make any change

Comment: Check to see whether `/tmp/emacs1002/server` exists after running `emacs --daemon`.  In fact, how *are* you starting the daemon?  The session you've shown doesn't show that at all.

Comment: I have following in the `.bashrc` => `export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""; export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"`. And I am just running `emacsclient -t -q <filename>` (it was handled on the background, I believe).  //After running `emacs --daemon` , `/tmp/emacs1002/server` exists but emacs closes itself right after printing `Error: Could not start the Emacs daemon`

Comment: Ok, break it down and check assumptions at each step.  (0) `unset ALTERNATE_EDITOR`.  (1) delete the socket (either manually or with `M-x server-force-delete`) and confirm that `/tmp/emacs1002/server` does not exist.  (2) run `emacsclient -t` and confirm that it doesn't think there's an existing server.  (3) run `emacs --daemon` and confirm that `/tmp/emacs1002/server` *does* exist again.  (4) run `emacsclient -t` and check whether you get the same problem as before.

Comment: debug output: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/b68e754922ba0a449e027f5b10817c22 // now problem is `emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?`

Comment: On step 3, after running `emacs --daemon` // server exists again. `ls -l` => `srwx------ 1 netlab netlab 0 Jul 16 01:13 /tmp/emacs1002/server`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the issue is, but you can clarify the question *substantially* now.  Nothing to do with X11, for starters (so far as I can see).  The main point seems to be that `emacsclient` can't read the socket created by the daemon.  Please edit the details of the steps you went through into the question, so that other people can see them more easily.  Perhaps repeat it using `emacs -Q --daemon` so that you don't get so much output.  Also, use `ls -l` rather than `cat` to check for the socket file in the first instance... the latter is less obvious.

Comment: And of course, show again in the steps that you've killed all emacs processes before you started.

Comment: I updated the questions hope it is clearer

Comment: Much clearer!  Also, based on `/snap/emacs/296/usr/bin/emacs` I think I know what your actual problem is -- don't use `snap` to install Emacs.  Apparently it's buggy.

Comment: (With the caveat that I haven't been able to find the discussion I'm remembering, so I might be wrong; but IIRC you're not the first person to have emacs client/server problems with this kind of installation.)

Comment: https://github.com/tealeg/emacs-snap/issues/1 would seem relevant, though.

Comment: Ah I messed up ubuntu packages and unable to reinstall emacs through `apt-get` so I hard-link it into binary that is installed by `snap` (sorry I forget to mention in the question). Let me  try to install via source code. Should I install the latest version i think it was v28, or v26.

Comment: Either 26.3 (current stable release) or the latest pretest for 27 (or the `emacs-27` branch).  Don't use 28 unless you're getting involved in the development... that's the `master` branch, which is unstable.

Comment: I was able to install `v26.3` but now emacs is v28.0.50 (apt-get installs the latest version). But I am able to run `emacsclient26 -t doo`, but it does not start with my `~.emacs` file

Comment: If you ended up with `28.0.50` then you compiled the master branch (or used someone else's build from that).  `apt-get` absolutely won't be installing that version (unless you've added some apt package repository with unstable builds).  If you compiled from git, I would `git checkout emacs-27` and start over with that.  If you got 28.0.50 from somewhere else.... probably look for a different source?

Comment: I verify that installing emacs v26.3 from `apt-get` (`sudo apt-get install emacs26` than I linked `emacs26` to `emacs`) fixed the issue.  I found the installing `snap` approach from this link (https://askubuntu.com/a/1238505/660555) maybe updating it or leaving a comment might help futher users to in case known the socket issue.

Comment: I believe running following command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs` lead `apt-get` to install `emacs v28` and it was much trouble to downgrade it.

Comment: This got reported to me upstream - https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap/issues/16 - but I am unable to reproduce it - @alper I would be happy to try and help debug this further with you if needed - please come join the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hands up here (https://github.com/tealeg/emacs-snap/issues/1#issuecomment-660462402) and `@phils`'s help on comments

> It seems the current snap is https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap

I made a clean installation using [`Alex Murray`'s `snap`](https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap) (*emacs 26.3 from Alex Murray*). I verify that `emacs --daemon` works perfectly fine.

---

#### The mistake I made:

When I was facing the error, I believe I I have used following ppa link :-(  =>  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs` due to this documentation (https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_emacs_installation/), which had the socket problem related to `emacs --daemon` issue I faced.

---